# Is there any way to disable a YouTube video from automatically starting in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, youtube

I have a couple of videos open on Firefox. As I refer to them often, I prefer to keep them as a tab rather than as a bookmark. However, every time I reboot Firefox, they start to play. Can I have them come up but not start to play until I select them to start? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Install Stop Autoplay Extension from Mozilla could be the best answer** https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1765/
- **You can stop all the video following any of these methods mentioned here** 
  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/stop-youtube-videos-from-automatically-playing-in-firefox/

Comment: This also seems interesting.+1. I will try it as soon as I can remove flashblock. Thanks.

Comment: This was gone by the time I got there, but I found https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6648/ so you will get the accept. Thanks.

Comment: @Xavierjazz and subanki: Both https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6648/ and https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1765/ are now not available for download and are marked as having "been removed by its author".

Answer (score 4):

As of [Firefox 69](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/69.0/releasenotes/), you can now [configure Firefox' settings to block all or specific websites from autoplaying videos](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-autoplay).

To always allow or disallow autoplay for all videos or media with sound:

1. Click the menu button [image: menu button] and choose *Options*.
2. Select the *Privacy & Security* panel.
3. Scroll down to the *Permissions* section.
4. Go to [image] Autoplay → Settings. *Default for all websites: Block audio* is the default setting. Set this to *Block Audio and Video* to block videos too. Or set this to *Allow Audio and Video* and you can configure blocking autoplay on a per-site setting, instead.

Youtube.com's site permissions will look like this if set to block video autoplay. You can also opt to set the autoplay permission to allow autoplaying videos for youtube.com only and not other sites.

[image: Youtube.com Firefox site permissions]

---

Firefox versions prior to 69 can use the [**YouTube High Definition**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/youtube-high-definition/) extension (also a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-high-definition/dokdlgjaaaijndfajoknjbelmadhomca?hl=en)) to stop YouTube from auto playing videos, among other features:

[image: YouTube High Definition screenshot - disable YouTube auto-play]

Answer (score 2):

Probably late (just by 6 years!), but if you don't want to install an extension, you can use the [Firefox configuration editor](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-config-editor-firefox) and change the `media.autoplay.enabled` value to `false`

Comment: Firefox now has a setting: `media.block-autoplay-until-in-foreground` that does exactly what you need, without the extra hassle that disabling auto-play has.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with **firefox 63**, the preference setting to disable autoplay has changed as answered in [Firefox support](https://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/1238380):

> in **about:config** you can set *media.autoplay.default*
>
> - to 1 in order to block automatic playback on all pages
> - to 2 to decide on a per domain basis.

NB: In future release, this feature will be accessible in ***Options*** ([source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-autoplay))

Answer (score 1):

[FlashBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashblock/) can do this.

Comment: FlashBlock is not working for me, youtube keeps on playing. Indeed, Firefox is crashing soon after being launched. When I go to "add-ons" I do not see the installed Flashblock and seem to have no way to remove it. How can I remove it? Perhaps I am looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Firefox has a safe-mode which allows you to disable troublesome extensions. How to run it depends in your platform though..

Comment: @remyhorton -  thanks, I guess, but really, this is no help. How about some direction? Regards,

Comment: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Safe+Mode

Answer (score 1):

Download [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox.

Download the [YouTube Enhancer userscript](http://web.archive.org/web/20140311072630/http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/33042).

At the top of the window, there is an option where you can set automatic buffering to off or autoplay to off. Same consequence, but with auto buffer, you need to wait for it to buffer (no problem on fast internet anyway).

Also other goodies as well:

- loop
- kill stream
- loop between two set points
- change quality easily

Comment: This looks interesting -+1. I will try this as soon as I am sure I removed Flashblock. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firefox now has a setting: `media.block-autoplay-until-in-foreground` that does exactly what you need. Set it to true through `about:config`.

This is better than changing the `media.autoplay.enabled` as it can have an adverse effect on you browsing experience (nothing autoplays)

Answer (score 0):

If you install the NoScript plug-in for Firefox it will block YouTube videos from loading automatically. You can then simply allow the Javascript/JAVA/Flash object every time you wish to view it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried various `about:config` settings with no success (using Youtube as a benchmark), but after some seaching I found [this article](https://www.cnet.com/news/firefox-users-finally-get-option-to-block-autoplay-video-audio/) mentioning that the feature is coming, and that it is already present in the nightly build.

> The autoplay blocking option works only in the Nightly test version of Firefox for now, but it's scheduled to arrive in the main version of the browser in October

Ironically, that very article started playing super loud and annoying ads in the bottom corner when I opened it.

**Firefox Nightly can be [downloaded and installed alongside regular Firefox from this page](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/channel/desktop/).**

I installed Nightly and can confirm that this works both on the above mentioned Cnet article as well as on Youtube. Since Firefox Nightly as a bonus now also allows me to multi-select tabs by Shift-clicking and moving them around (a la Chrome), I'm sold.

[image: Firefox asks you whether to block auto-playing videos]

Please note that you need to completely exit Firefox before you'll be able to actually launch Nightly. At least for me, in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022/07/22 in Mozilla Firefox 103.0, none of these solutions were working for me. It seems like websites have found a way to defeat the "block autoplay" setting exposed in the GUI.

The `about:config` changes in [this guide](https://www.alphr.com/stop-autoplay-videos-firefox/) were the only solution that led to consistent blocking of autoplay across domains and various scenarios. The applied setting changes were:

```
media.autoplay.default = 5
media.autoplay.blocking_policy = 2
media.autoplay.allow-extension-background-pages = false
media.autoplay.block-event.enabled = true
```