# Not start movie by default on YouTube?

Tags: firefox, youtube

I like to go to YouTube and open a few (1-10) movies in tabs and after it has loaded I watch it (I have to manually pause every movie after I open it). Is there some way to make YouTube pause it by default? (any YouTube preference or maybe Firefox Plugin?)

Comment: This would also be handy for when doing "open in new tab" on links that don't advertise their destination being youtube (i.e., redirected through a link shortener). Avoiding the unexpected audio followed by the search to find and pause/close the clip would be a Good Thing.

Comment: Given that the solution is a Firefox extension, migrating this to Web Apps seems a bit churlish.

Comment: Related: [Is there any way to disable a YouTube video from automatically starting in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/q/186143/10259)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/179387/ this is the most community endorsed addon ive found that does what you want. Apparently it does a lot of other youtubey things too.

Comment: this one also does the job [tubestop](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tubestop/) i love it because it also removes ads

Answer (score 1):

And some scripts may help: YouTube Auto Pause On Tab/Window Change >  http://wescript.net/scripts/18923

Answer (score 1):

There's a handy script called [YouTube Auto Buffer & Auto HD & Remove Ads for Greasemonkey](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/49366).

Have a look at my [screenshot](https://superuser.com/questions/487361/how-can-i-stop-youtube-videos-from-auto-playing/488314#488314), usage is self-explaining.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [YouTube Control Center](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-control-center/) open source add-on to configure autoplay behavior, buffering and much more.