# How can I stop YouTube videos from auto-playing?

Tags: firefox, plugins, youtube

I was using "Stop YouTube Autoplay" add-on to stop autoplaying the videos thus saving bandwidth. But since 1.0.3, this Firefox plugin doesn't work anymore.

Is there any other FF plugin that does the same? Browser version is 16.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Flashblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashblock/) addon. Another alternative is [TubeStop](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tubestop/).

Comment: Excellent!! It works, thank you :)  I've one more question: please watch this as example ~ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8DG72R6pqw  I would like to know is it possible (by this plugin or any other) to see the picture of the first frame of the video (of course with blocked auto-play & video buffering)? This could help in downloading the right content or file. Thanks again

Comment: Flashblock does not provide a preview since it blocks the video from loading, even a bit. From the reviews of Tubestop, it seems like it provided a preview feature but doesn't work in the recent times.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer. I think I'm happy with Flashblock, but I'll try Tubestop too :)

Answer (score 2):

Use Firefox's built-in "click-to-play" feature. This prevents ALL plugins from automatically playing until you click on it, saving you bandwidth.

1. Open a new tab and go to `about:config?filter=plugins.click_to_play`.
2. Press "I'll be careful, I promise".
3. Double click on the `plugins.click_to_play` preference to set it to `true`.

You can also allow plugins to [automatically run on certain websites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyj1e.png) by clicking on the plugin icon in the address bar -> clicking on the down arrow -> always activate plugins for this site.

Comment: Browser config does work but it's making FF to choke PLUS this setting can't stop video buffer. So one can't save Bandwidth even though it stops auto-play by default

Answer (score 2):

If playing the video with the flash-plugin, you could give [YouTube Auto Buffer & Auto HD & Remove Ads for Greasemonkey](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/49366) a try.

Set the option for Auto[buffer/play] to 'Both off'.

[image]

Comment: I don't use Flash plugin (disabled it) as it makes the life of FF (memory/performance) hell. Thank you for the response. I shall remember this tool too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [YouTube Control Center](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-control-center/) open source add-on to configure autoplay behavior, buffering and much more.