# Firefox plugin to disable / block WebM video

Tags: firefox, html5, plugins

I'm accustomed to using the FlashBlock plugin to disable those annoying advertisements that play automatically, but I'm unaware of any available plugin that accomplishes the same thing with WebM content.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable HTML5 content in popular browsers like Firefox and Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/670214/how-can-i-disable-html5-content-in-popular-browsers-like-firefox-and-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This add-on appears to block autoplay](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stop-autoplay/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This solution would be more permanent than I would like; the FlashBlock plugin has everything blocked by default, but allows one to click on anything you want to un-block.  This is why I was hoping for a similar plugin.

Comment: @Withnail If you already have Greasemonkey installed there are some other tricks you can do, like allowing the video to be visible but disabling autoplay.  Have a look [on this page](http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html#markup), there's a User Script near the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I'm going to leave this one open for now, until someone runs across a Firefox plugin.

Comment: @Withnail [This add-on appears to block autoplay](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stop-autoplay/)

Comment: Much obliged!  Perhaps you could turn the comment into the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: At the link provided "This add-on has been removed by its author."

Comment: @Magicianeer Yeah, looks like you've found [the same bug I did](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=659285) too.  If you write an extensions let me know and I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to kill HTML5 totally in my Firefox, until flashblock supports it;
and I'm trying to bribe the flashblock developers with my hard-earned cash...

meanwhile:

```
about:config
search: media.
media.autoplay.enabled = false
media.ogg.enabled = false
media.wav.enabled = false
media.webm.enabled = false
```

Now, tell me how to do it in chrome!

You could also use `media.autoplay.enabled = false` by itself,
but Youtube cheats its way around that, so need this add-on too:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stop-youtube-autoplay/

See also:  http://rubenerd.com/noscript-html5/  but I think noscript permanently disables the videos, no click-to-play; can only white-list the whole site.

Answer (score 0):

I have [written an answer for this](https://superuser.com/a/1370087/36197) that should apply to all videos. It's basically a native feature available in Firefox Nightly (but also hopefully in the stable channel soon).