# Dell precision T3600 & T3630 series hate YAHOO

Tags: dell-precision

I own many Dell desktops and laptops.

The Precision T3600 and T3630 are very good. But for some reason, they all hate Yahoo.

yahoo.com is always slow to display and the page layout is so cluttered that it barely displays well for me, and Yahoo email is nearly unusable, Yahoo finance is basically stuck. Other web sites other than Yahoo have no problem at all.

I tried Firefox, Edge, Google Chrome and they all had the same confusing results and difficulties.

I even use a new hard drive and freshly installed Windows 10 Pro (on T3600) and 11 Pro (on T3630) but the problem persists. Therefore, it should not be caused by a virus.

I tried every version of the BIOS, from the oldest to the newest, but nothing helped.

Other computers connected to the same router/modem have no issues, so it's not an issue with my network.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Is media set to autoplay? [Turn that off](https://superuser.com/questions/670214/how-can-i-disable-html5-content-in-popular-browsers-like-firefox-and-chrome).
2. Check that the bottleneck is not the Windows OS and its drivers: create bootable media having another OS, such as [Ubuntu 20.04 Live](https://linuxhint.com/run_ubuntu_usb_stick/), and see if Yahoo loads more rapidly.
3. The main page of Yahoo.com requests DRM checks. To see if that is causing a delay, turn **off** DRM in the browser. E.G., in Firefox, Settings, Search on DRM and uncheck *Play DRM-controlled content*. [BTW, most Yahoo! content works well *without* DRM.]
4. Could there be something in your profiles on those machines causing an issue?

   - Use private browsing. mode, and/or try [Brave browser](https://brave.com/) to help avoid identification.
   - Remove *all* cookies.
   - Use a tool such as [User Agent Switcher and Manager](https://add0n.com/useragent-switcher.html) to help avoid fingerprinting.
   - Use a VPN.