# How do I stop YouTube autoplay in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I want to disable YouTube autoplay in Google Chrome.

I followed the instructions in [How to Disable YouTube Video Autoplay](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/stop-youtube-autoplay/)

I went to `chrome://chrome/settings/content` and changed the settings to "Click to Play".

It worked, but a few days ago it stopped working and YouTube videos started to autoplay again on my computer. How do I disable autoplay in Google Chrome without installing any plugin?  I'm using Google Chrome in Windows.

**2022-02-19 update**: If you don't use any plugin or extension, you can't stop sound/video/music from auto-playing on any website which the website admin has set to autoplay. The only way to stop autoplay is not to use Chrome.

This problem has bothered me for years, but Google doesn't want it to be possible to disable autoplay on Chrome.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem: despite having "Click to play" enabled (and no exception for YouTube), videos automatically start playing the moment I land on a YouTube video page.

Comment: I think it's because the videos play with HTML5 and not Flash.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. Is there a way to stop auto-play (basically auto-load) of HTML5 videos on YouTube?

Comment: Related (for Firefox): [Is there any way to disable a YouTube video from automatically starting in Firefox?](http://superuser.com/q/186143/10259)

Answer (score 8):

**I went to chrome://settings/content and changed the settings to "Click to Play".**

This only works with Flash Videos. YouTube now uses `HTML5 Video`. The only way to disable `auto-play` is through an extension like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-html5-autoplay/efdhoaajjjgckpbkoglidkeendpkolai?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog). `Auto-loading` video can also be disabled through [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/magic-actions-for-youtube/abjcfabbhafbcdfjoecdgepllmpfceif?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) extension.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can do it without a plugin, sorry. You can look at the other answers here for suggested plugins.

*Note the statement was true in 2014 when it was written. Someone down-voted it more than four years later without stating a reason. Technology changes quickly and obviously old answers might become obsolete, so please take that into consideration and add updates in comments when necessary (as far as I know, there is no working solution without plugin in 2020). Thanks.*

Answer (score 2):

Chrome will defer autoplay in *background* tabs in one of the next versions (46 most likely, to be released in late October). It is not yet in 45 (which is stable at the time of writing), but Canary (48) does not autoplay YouTube in background tabs when the browser is opened. I like it. However, if you pull one of the YouTube-Tabs to the foreground, the video will still start to play automatically.

Source: [Blog post by François Beaufort](https://plus.google.com/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/6PiJQqJzGqX) (who also gives away the target version 46 in the comments)

Answer (score 2):

Try these two chrome extensions:

[YouTube™ No Buffer (Stop Auto-playing)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-no-buffer-stop-au/afgfpcfjdgakemlmlgadojdfnejkpegd?hl=en)
[YouTube™ Stop Button](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-stop-button/ahcnccjmpopcpcfhpoddjiglaoiaeaad/related?hl=en)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: the only solution that worked with me all other extensions failed ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stop-youtube-html5-autopl/ajkibmginjljbmmpgnipfbcbmkcodaap

This plugin worked for me. I'm not a big fan of plugins but until I find a better way..

Answer (score 1):

I used this plugin

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/magic-actions-for-youtube/abjcfabbhafbcdfjoecdgepllmpfceif/related

It has a bundle of other options I want to have set other then just no autoplay.

Answer (score 1):

The [**AutoplayStopper**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoplaystopper/ejddcgojdblidajhngkogefpkknnebdh?hl=en) Chrome extension can stop Flash and HTML5 media from autoplaying in YouTube and other sites. It will show the video preview thumbnail instead of autoplaying.

[image: AutoplayStopper in action.]

---

The [**YouTube High Definition**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-high-definition/dokdlgjaaaijndfajoknjbelmadhomca?hl=en) Chrome extension (also a [Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/youtube-high-definition/)) can be configured to stop YouTube from auto playing videos, among other features:

[image: YouTube High Definition screenshot - disable YouTube auto-play]

Answer (score 0):

Use the "autostop" feature in the Turn Off the Lights Browser extension 
(for Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Microsoft Edge):
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/turn-off-the-lights/bfbmjmiodbnnpllbbbfblcplfjjepjdn
https://www.turnoffthelights.com
This stop playing automatically the HTML5 videos on all websites (with YouTube support).

Answer (score 0):

### **Solution without a plugin**

Disable autoplay on Chrome desktop for recent version (chrome 68)

First, copy and paste

```
chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy
```

into Google Chrome’s URL bar.
This will take you directly to a Chrome flag that you can change.

The Autoplay policy is set to

> Default

when you load the page.
You’ll need to set the drop box option box to

> Document user activation  is required

so that you have to approve any video to play on a website.

Lastly, you’ll need to click on the blue Relaunch Now button found at the bottom of the page in order to activate the change.

**More information**

---

[source for this tweak](https://9to5google.com/2018/02/15/how-to-disable-autoplay-videos-chrome/)
[Official developper information about autoplay function](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/audio-video/autoplay)

Comment: `chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy` has since been removed

Comment: This answer needs to be revised, the flag is no longer part of chrome.

Answer (score -1):

it's very simple. You can stop autoplay on youtube by clicking the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2fXf.png)disable autoplay button